# what is the reason of calculating duration in Microsoft Project in decimal form?

Tags: ms-project-2013

when I enter the start times and end times of tasks, software calculates duration of task in decimal form. I have checked calender setting and I think it is correct but I can't solve this problem.
I don't know what should I do?

Comment: I'd check the default start and end times in File > Options.  As an aside, you shouldn't be entering start and end dates or times of tasks - those should be calculated by Project - unless you are working solely with manually scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Durations are tracked by MS Project to the minute level. Using decimals in durations allows detail in durations for:

- tasks starting or ending at times other than the work day start and finish that you define as defaults
- tasks that take fractional amounts of a day, say 2.5 hours, at resource usage of 100%

Also, decimals allow easier aggregations of these for summarization.